# When I copy my HTML from an old page into TextEdit, I get garbage symbols

Tags: html

I try to copy my html code from an old page of mine to use in a new page(with new pictures and text), and I get garbage symbols. Im using Text Edit on a Mavericks Mac.

The html code looks correct in TextEdit, but when I look at the new code in any browser, the source gives me what I did not copy in. And if I type it into TextEdit extremely carefully, it still is garbage when I look at source. Its driving me whacky. This did not happen with my previous Mac.

Comment: First, are you copying the source, or the html output?  Generally you should be coping source to source I think.  Also what encoding is the html page set to (look at the meta tags), and what is your editor set to use, e.g. ASCII, ANSI, UTF-8, etc?  They need to agree.  And please say what editor, what OS, and do you know how to capture a screen shot?  Best to post a screen shot here.

Answer (score 0):

textEdit is a rich text editor and not really suited to coding.  it tries to apply character set changes when you copy/paste/save/open.  This is quite different from notepad on windows which works fine for code (although notepad is full of huge bugs and really limited... but that's another topic).

I suggest you install a great free code editor called text wrangler.  It's the standard first choice for code editing on a mac when you need something quickly, free, and easily.  I have no affiliation with the product or company - it's just the standard best first quick choice for your needs on a mac.

You'll have constant headaches with textEdit for code editing.

http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/